# How to know Cube build have finished

Tags: kylin

I am using Kylin REST API to submit Cube build request, Kylin will build the cube asynchronously,
I would ask how to know that the Cube build request has been finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following REST endpoint to get the status of the cube

```
GET http://localhost:7070/kylin/api/jobs/{job_uuid}
```

in the returned json objec the field `job_status`  would show the status of the cube build.

Comment: Thanks @nissanka-seneviratne. But, how to get the `job_uuid` as the parameter for this request? I found that the `build` request returns a JobInstance object, but it looks that this object doesn't contain `job uuid`

Comment: I double checked the JobInstance class, it does include `job_uuid` property